# Remote updating sqlite database in iOS tableview app

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data, tableview

What would be the best way to remotely update a tableview with new elements + an attached file to that element? I want to send new jobs to my workers on the field and I need some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understood your question right, what you want to use are web services that update a remote database on a server. This can be done in Java or PHP (these are the 2 ways I'm aware of)

Comment: Pe ym. Poate imi explici mai bine. Mersi!